# marking a point in the boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am plotting three different sets as three boxplot in 1 page using ggplot2. In each set there is a point that I would like to highlight, and illustrate where the point stands compare to the others, is it inside the box ? or the outside.

Here is my datapoint

```
    CDH     1KG     NHLBI
CDH 301     688     1762
RS0 204     560     21742
RS1 158     1169    1406
RS2 182     1945    1467
RS3 256     2371    1631
RS4 198     580     1765
RS5 193     524     1429
RS6 139     2551    1469
RS7 188     702     1584
RS8 142     4311    1461
RS9 223     916     1591
RS10 250    794     1406
RS11 185    539     1270
RS12 228    641     1786
RS13 152    557     1677
RS14 225    1970    1619
RS15 196    458     1543
RS16 203    2891    1528
RS17 221    1542    1780
RS18 258    1173    1850
RS19 202    718     1651
RS20 191    6314    1564


library(ggplot2) 
rm(list = ls())
orig_table = read.table("thedata.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
bb = orig_table # have copy of the data
bb = bb[,-1] # since these points, the ones in the first raw are my interesting point, I exclude them from the sets for the time being
tt = bb
mydata = cbind(c(tt[,1], tt[,2], tt[,3]), c(rep(1,22),rep(2,22),rep(3,22))) # I form the dataframe
data2 = cbind(c(301,688,1762),c(1,2,3)) # here is the points that I want to highlight - similar to the first raw
colnames(data2) = c("num","gro")
data2 = as.data.frame(data2) # I form them as a dataframe 

colnames(mydata) = c("num","gro")
mydata = as.data.frame(mydata)
mydata$gro = factor(mydata$gro, levels=c(1,2,3))
qplot(gro, num, data=mydata, geom=c("boxplot"))+scale_y_log10() # I am making the dataframe out of 21 other ponts
# and here I want to highlight those three values in the "data2" dataframe
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Highlight how? Just make those three points a different color?

Comment: yes - making them in "red, blue, green" would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ggplot is a lot easier to use if you use data in long format.  `melt` from `reshape2` helps with that:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df$highlight <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, nrow(df) - 1L))  # tag first row as interesting
df.2 <- melt(df)  # convert df to long format
ggplot(subset(df.2, !highlight), aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10() +
  geom_point(                               # add the highlight points
    data=subset(df.2, highlight), 
    aes(x=variable, y=value), 
    color="red", size=5
  )
```

Now, all I did was add a TRUE, to the first row, melted the data to be compatible with ggplot, and plotted the points with highlight==TRUE in addition to the boxplots.

[image]

EDIT: this is how I made the data:

```
df <- read.table(text="    CDH     1KG     NHLBI
CDH 301     688     1762
RS0 204     560     21742
RS1 158     1169    1406
RS2 182     1945    1467
RS3 256     2371    1631
RS4 198     580     1765
RS5 193     524     1429
RS6 139     2551    1469
RS7 188     702     1584
RS8 142     4311    1461
RS9 223     916     1591
RS10 250    794     1406
RS11 185    539     1270
RS12 228    641     1786
RS13 152    557     1677
RS14 225    1970    1619
RS15 196    458     1543
RS16 203    2891    1528
RS17 221    1542    1780
RS18 258    1173    1850
RS19 202    718     1651
RS20 191    6314    1564", header=T)
```

Comment: thanks - sorry for asking this - it seems you have used different names for the variable. Basically, I don't know how have you formed df and it is there ? is it same as "mydata" or it is "bb" ?

Comment: @user702846 I just used the text table at the top of your post.  The X got added to 1KG because variable names aren't allowed to start with a 1, I think.  That can be fixed.  What variable names do you want?

Comment: I read the matrix into df, and then ran your code. R complains about "highlight", in the subset function.

Comment: regarding your note. Well, I don't think it would be misleading if I make the boxplot without the interesting points. Because my aim is to show, how far are these points from the those distributions. They are not necessarily part of the distributions.

Comment: @user702846 I added the data creation step, you should try with that.  Hard for me to know what's going wrong if your data is in a different format.  Also, will update to make the boxplots w/o the first row in a minute.

Comment: Also, what error do you get? `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'highlight' not found`?  If so make sure you include the step where `highlight` is added to the input data frame before the `melt` step.

Comment: I replace it with df$highlight and now works !! fantastic !! did you said you can make it w/o the interesting point involved !?

Comment: @user702846 yes code is now modified to work w/o point (note the new `subset`)